# Reading from a stream of strings and numbers delimited by commas

Tags: streams

I am trying to read from a stream of strings and numbers *delimited by commas* similar to the way I have read from a stream of strings and numbers *delimited by spaces*.

---

**Example delimited by spaces (which works):**

```
stream = StringToStream["Apple Jack 1 123.456\nOrange Jill 2 456.789\n"];
While[! EndOfFile  === (data = 
      Read[stream, { Word, Word, Number, Number }]),
 Print["Fruit:", data[[1]], " Name:", data[[2]],
      " Integer:", data[[3]], " Real:", data[[4]]];
]
```

*Results:*

```
Fruit:Apple Name:Jack Integer:1 Real:123.456
Fruit:Orange Name:Jill Integer:2 Real:456.789
```

---

**Example delimited by commas (which does not work):**

```
stream = StringToStream["Apple,Jack,1,123.456\nOrange,Jill,2,456.789\n"];
While[! EndOfFile  === (data = 
      Read[stream, { Word, Word, Number, Number }]),
 Print["Fruit:", data[[1]], " Name:", data[[2]],
      " Integer:", data[[3]], " Real:", data[[4]]];
]
```

*Results:*

```
Fruit:Apple,Jack,1,123.456 Name:Orange,Jill,2,456.789 Integer:EndOfFile Real:EndOfFile
```

It appears that commas are not default separators.

---

**I added `WordSeparators -> ","` as an option to `Read`.** Note `NumberSeparator` is not valid option for `Read`.

```
stream = StringToStream["Apple,Jack,1,123.456\nOrange,Jill,2,456.789\n"];
While[! EndOfFile  === (data = 
      Read[stream, { Word, Word, Number, Number }, {WordSeparators -> ","}]),
 Print["Fruit:", data[[1]], " Name:", data[[2]],
       " Integer:", data[[3]], " Real:", data[[4]]];
 ]
```

*Results:*

```
Read::readn: Invalid real number found when reading from StringToStream[Apple,Jack,1,123.456
Orange,Jill,2,456.789
]. >>

Fruit:Apple Name:Jack Integer:$Failed Real:EndOfFile

Read::readn: Invalid real number found when reading from StringToStream[Apple,Jack,1,123.456
Orange,Jill,2,456.789
]. >>

Fruit:1 Name:123.456 Integer:$Failed Real:EndOfFile
...
```

Well this works for words, but not for numbers.

---

**I can always do this, but this seems a little overkill:**

```
stream = StringToStream["Apple,Jack,1,123.456\nOrange,Jill,2,456.789\n"];
While[! EndOfFile  === (record = Read[stream, Record]),
 data = MapAt[ToExpression, StringSplit[record, ","], {{3}, {4}}];
 Print["Fruit:", data[[1]], " Name:", data[[2]],
      " Integer:", data[[3]], " Real:", data[[4]]];
]
```

*Results:*

```
Fruit:Apple Name:Jack Integer:1 Real:123.456
Fruit:Orange Name:Jill Integer:2 Real:456.789
```

Is there something thing that I am missing with `Read`?

### Post answer analysis ...

The check was awarded to the answer that best answered the above question as I am not one to change the rules of the game while it is being played.  However the question was flawed by an assumption that I made that both the parsing and conversion in `Read` would be the most efficient.

If one is looking for the most efficient solution, the following are some results from answers presented (timings are in seconds for 10000 iterations):

```
        Implementation         |  Timing 
-------------------------------+---------
question - Read[] with spaces  | 0.220325
Matariki - wo/Sequence[]       | 0.250499
Matariki - w/Sequence[]        | 0.345603
Heike - Word, Word, Word, Word | 0.351137
Heike - Riffle                 | 0.380684
question - overkill            | 0.395058
```

Comment: I guess you could read all records as words and use `ToExpression` to turn them into numbers.

Comment: Have you tried instead of using `Word, Word, Number, Number` to use `Word, Word, Number, Real`?

Comment: @Matariki - yeap same results as Word, Word, Number, Number.

Comment: @Heike - Yeap ... your suggestion no longer requires splitting, but still requires the conversion. I was hopping someone knew of a super secret option to Read that would allow commas as separators. I guess I must be misusing yet another Mathematica function for domination of the world. ;)

Comment: I'd contend that you're seeing a bug. The problem is the comma between the two number's. Simple testing using `Word` shows that the comma is not removed until the next token is pulled from the stream, and while `Word` will respect the `WordSeparators`, `Number` does not. It insists on whitespace only. It seems clear that `WordSeparators` is intended as a list of field separators, but it doesn't act that way.

Comment: @mmorris I've edited the last part to remove the "Result" column, as it was pushing away the more important "Timing" column and one would've had to scroll to see it. Also, I though that column was redundant, as any solution that you consider here _should_ give the correct result which you've already presented in the question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work and doesn't require conversion

```
stream = StringToStream[
   "Apple,Jack,1,123.456\nOrange,Jill,2,456.789\n"];

While[! EndOfFile === (data = 
      Read[stream, Riffle[{Word, Word, Number, Number}, Word],
        TokenWords -> {","}] /. {"," -> Sequence[]}), 
  Print["Fruit:", data[[1]], " Name:", data[[2]], " Integer:", 
    data[[3]], " Real:", data[[4]]];];

Close[stream];
```

Comment: Nice. No need for extra storage space in `data`. +1

Comment: Earns the check (unless that _super secret_ `Read` option shows up) because it is a more general purpose solution.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
stream = StringToStream[
   "Apple,Jack,1,123.456\nOrange,Jill,2,456.789\n"];
While[! EndOfFile === (data = 
     Read[stream, {Word, Word, Character, Number, Character, Number}, 
      WordSeparators -> ","]), 
 Print["Fruit:", data[[1]], " Name:", data[[2]], " Integer:", 
   data[[4]], " Real:", data[[6]]];]
```

Having learnd something from Heike's answer I add `/. {"," -> Sequence[]}` which removes the commmas and there is no need to skip the them in `data`.

```
stream = StringToStream[
   "Apple,Jack,1,123.456\nOrange,Jill,2,456.789\n"];
While[! EndOfFile === (data = 
     Read[stream, {Word, Word, Character, Number, Character, Number}, 
      WordSeparators -> ","] /. {"," -> Sequence[]}), 
 Print["Fruit:", data[[1]], " Name:", data[[2]], " Integer:", 
   data[[3]], " Real:", data[[4]]];]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using `ImportString`?

```
ImportString["Apple,Jack,1,123.456\nOrange,Jill,2,456.789\n", "CSV"]
```

> ```
> {{"Apple", "Jack", 1, 123.456}, {"Orange", "Jill", 2, 456.789}}
> ```

Comment: I have used `Import` and `ImportString` in the past, unfortunately in this particular instance I need to read from a stream.  The use of `stream = StringToStream["Apple Jack 1 123.456\nOrange Jill 2 456.789\n"];` is contrived so I could give a concise, but accurate example of my problem.